# .htaccess rewrite rule with static files gives me 404, what I'm missing?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silex

My project (Silex) has a front controller `web/index.php` and assets in `web/css/*`, `web/img/*` and so on. I've placed the following `.htaccess` file in the root of the public html folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Every request should be rewrited to web folder (`RewriteBase web` directive) and if file doesn't exist (`!-f`) it should be routed to the front controller.

This is not working:

```
<img src="/img/myimage.png" alt="" />
```

File `myimage.png` exists, but request for `/img/myimage.png` gives me a 404 folder. If I  modify the path to `/web/img/mmyimage.png` it works.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Try `RewriteBase /web`

Answer (score 0):

You could try routing the css and img folders explicitly:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(css|img) /web%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

You'd need to add that right before the condition for the index.php routing rule.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .htaccess with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if requested files exists in /web then forward it there
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /web/$1 [L]

# if requested files doesn't exist in /web then forward it to index.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /web/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

if your server is running Apache >= 2.2.16 you can use:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

in your .htaccess instead of

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

See also [Apache’s fallbackresource: your new .htaccess command](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/01/21/apaches-fallbackresource-your-new-htaccess-command/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change web to /web as Kyra mentioned.

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

But that's not going to solve your issue.

Main problem is your DocumentRoot is pointing to /path/to/project and it should point to /path/to/project/web

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with these lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web/$1 -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```