# Annoying Silex subdirectory .htaccess issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, silex

I'm working on a few projects using Silex and on none of them can I get the .htaccess file working. The current directory structure is `http://localhost/IIV/`

The front file in Silex is in `http://localhost/IIV/web/index.php`

This is what I have currently:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /IIV/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /web/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /web/index_dev.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you have parsing .htaccess files enabled in your apache config?

Comment: Have a look at the Apache command: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18893520/2243419

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your RewriteBase is wrong, try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /IIV/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, make sure Apache is configured to load the .htaccess rules as @Maerlyn mentioned above.